# Chinese Remainder Theorem in combination with Dirichlet's Theorem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, field-theory

Suppose that $a$,$b$ are two distinct primes. Let $r>0$. I want to show that for every $r>0$ there exists a prime $p$ such that $p\equiv 1\mod a^{r}$ and $p\equiv -1\mod b^{r}$. By CRT we know that there exists an integer $x$ such that $x\equiv 1\mod a^{r}$ and $x\equiv -1 \mod b^{r}$. Now my question is, how does one apply the Dirichlet theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions to complete the proof?

Comment: the chinese remainder theorem gives you an arithmetic progression of solutions.  You just need to check that the terms aren't all divisible by a common factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Lulu's comment I think that this is the solution:

Since $x$ is a solution we find the arithmetic progression $\{x+na^{r}b^{r}\}_{n}$ consisting of solutions. And we clearly see that since $x = ka^{r} + 1 = mb^{r}-1$ for some $k,l\in\mathbb{Z}$ that $gcd(x,a^{r}b^{r}) = 1$. Then by Dirichlet's theorem we find that there exists infinitely many prime satisfying $p\equiv x\mod a^{r}b^{r}$. So $p = x + sa^{r}b^{r}$, which indeed satisfies $p\equiv 1 \mod a^{r}$ and $p\equiv -1 \mod b^{r}$.

So if im right, we can actually find for every $r>0$ infinitely many primes $p$ satisfying $p\equiv 1 \mod a^{r}$ and $p\equiv -1\mod b^{r}$.